# Buscar palavras que contém determinada letra

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Estou precisando fazer uma busca com a biblioteca `re` para quando eu passar uma letra, retornar a palarva toda contendo a letra.

```
text = "Texto de busca por palavras contendo a letra z, como por exemplo 
        zebra, zoologico. A letra z sozinha nao sera retornado na busca."

 # fazendo a busca assim o codigo retorna do z para frente
 re.findall(r'z\w+', text)
 ['zebra', 'zoologico', 'zinha']

 # fazendo assim ele retorna so palavras que contenham o z no meio
 re.findall(r'\w+z\w+', text)
 ['sozinha']
```

Será que teria alguma forma de retornar todas as palavras que contenham a letra `z`?

Comment: você aceitou a resposta com regex, e ok, já que foi a pergutna foi feita explicitamente para regex - mas eu sugiro fortemente você usar, no seu código, a versão sem regez, que usa simplesmente Python puro `letra in palavra` - 'e muito mais legível - e, para quase todas as aplicações,  ganho de performance com regex nesse caso (se houver de fato um ganho) será negligível.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Levando em conta que a sua variável `text` contém o trecho `"A letra z sozinha nao sera retornado na busca."`, estou assumindo que é isso que você precisa.

Sendo assim, uma maneira de fazer é usar [alternância](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html): o caractere `|`, que significa **ou**:

```
text = "Texto de busca por palavras contendo a letra z, como por exemplo zebra, zoologico. A letra z sozinha nao sera retornado na busca."
palavras = re.findall(r'\b(z[a-z]+|[a-z]+z|[a-z]+z[a-z]+)\b', text, re.I)
print(palavras) # ['zebra', 'zoologico', 'sozinha']
```

Assim, a regex tem 3 alternativas (separadas pelo `|`):

- uma palavra que começa com z: `z[a-z]+`, **ou**
- uma palavra que termina com z: `[a-z]+z`, **ou**
- uma palavra com z no meio: `[a-z]+z[a-z]+`

Se não quiser algum desses casos, basta retirar a respectiva alternativa. Por exemplo, se não quiser as palavras que contém um "z" no meio, e só quiser as que começam ou terminam com "z":

```
palavras = re.findall(r'\b(z[a-z]+|[a-z]+z)\b', text, re.I)
```

Antes e depois de tudo isso eu coloco `\b`, que é um atalho para [*word boundary*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) ("fronteira entre palavras", uma posição que possui um caractere alfanumérico antes e um não-alfanumérico depois, ou vice-versa), que garante que estou pegando uma palavra inteira. Isso evita que ela pegue somente o trecho "zinha" da palavra "sozinha".

Também estou assumindo que "palavra" é uma sequência de letras de `a` a `z`. O atalho `\w` também considera números (dígitos de 0 a 9) e o caractere `_`, então se quiser pegar somente as letras, use `[a-z]`.

Também usei a [*flag* `re.I`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.I) (*case insensitive*) para considerar letras maiúsculas e minúsculas. Sem esta *flag*, a regex acima só consideraria letras minúsculas.

---

O problema é que `[a-z]` não considera letras acentudadas. Você poderia mudá-la para algo como `[a-záâãàéêíî....]` (inclua todos os caracteres acentuados dentro dos colchetes), ou usar `\w` mesmo (sabendo que ele pode pegar números e `_`).

Ou ainda pode usar:

```
palavras = re.findall(r'\b(z[^\W\d_]+|[^\W\d_]+z|[^\W\d_]+z[^\W\d_]+)\b', text, re.I)
```

No caso, `[^....]` considera [tudo que **não** está entre colchetes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated). E dentro deles temos `\W` (que é "tudo que não for `\w`"), `\d` (números) e `_` (o próprio caractere `_`). Ou seja, é uma forma de dizer "`\w`, só que sem os números e `_`", que acaba pegando todas as letras, inclusive as acentuadas.

---

Outra alternativa é usar [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.split) para separar o texto em palavras, e em seguida eu verifico as que possuem um "z":

```
palavras = [ palavra for palavra in re.split(r'\W', text) if len(palavra) > 1 and 'z' in palavra.lower() ]
```

No `split` eu uso `\W`: tudo que não for um `\w` (letra, número ou `_`). Se quiser, também pode usar `[\W\d_]` para não considerar números e `_`.

Depois, eu pego as palavras que tem mais de um caractere (`len(palavra) > 1`) e que contém um "z". Isso elimina os casos em que somente o "z" está isolado. Eu também uso `'z' in palavra.lower()` para considerar tanto "z" minúsculo quanto maiúsculo, mas se quiser considerar somente o minúsculo, faça `'z' in palavra`.

Se quiser somente as que começam ou terminam com "z", pode mudar para:

```
palavras = [ palavra for palavra in re.split(r'[\W\d_]', text) if len(palavra) > 1 and (palavra.startswith('z') or palavra.endswith('z')) ]
```

E novamente, você pode usar `palavra.lower().startswith('z')` se quiser considerar "z" maiúsculo e minúsculo.

---

Uma outra alternativa, usando a ideia que o jsbueno deu nos comentários, é:

```
text = "Texto de busca por palavras contendo a letra z, como por exemplo zebra, zoológico. A letra z sozinha nao sera retornado na busca traz."
palavras = re.findall(r'\b(?=\w*z)\w{2,}\b', text, re.I)
print(palavras) # ['zebra', 'zoológico', 'sozinha', 'traz']
```

A ideia é usar um [*lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) (o trecho entre `(?=...)`) para verificar se existe um `z` depois de `\w*` (zero ou mais caracteres alfanuméricos). Ou seja, se existe um `z` em algum ponto de uma palavra.

O detalhe é que o *lookahead* só verifica se algo existe à frente, mas depois volta para o ponto onde estava e verifica o restante da regex. E o restante da regex é `\w{2,}` (dois ou mais caracteres alfanuméricos).

Ou seja, o *lookahead* garante que há um `z` que faz parte de uma palavra (podendo estar no início, meio ou fim), e o `\w{2,}` garante que tem pelo menos dois caracteres, descartando assim os casos do `z` sozinho.

---

**Obs**: mas se não tiver essa restrição de não considerar o "`z` sozinho", a regex fica (conforme lembrado pelo @fernandosavio nos comentários):

```
palavras = re.findall(r'\b[a-z]*z[a-z]*\b', text, re.I)
```

Que é "zero ou mais letras", a letra "z", e zero ou mais letras (lembrando que você pode trocar `[a-z]` por `\w` ou `[^\W\d_]`, conforme já explicado acima).

E na solução com `split`, basta remover a restrição do tamanho da string e só verificar se ela contém um "z":

```
palavras = [ palavra for palavra in re.split(r'[\W\d_]', text) if 'z' in palavra.lower() ]
```

Comment: Ao invés de usar alternância não seria mais simples usar o quantificador `*` ao invés do `+` para pegar zero ou mais ocorrências? No seu exemplo seria `[a-z]*z[a-z]*`...

Comment: @fernandosavio Não, porque essa regex pega o "z" sozinho: https://regex101.com/r/dGFFUk/2/

Comment: Mas não é isso que o AP quer? Pergunto por causa da última frase: "Será que teria alguma forma de retornar todas as palavras que contenham a letra z?"

Comment: @fernandosavio Bom, na variável `text` está a frase "A letra z sozinha nao sera retornado na busca", por isso eu concluí que ele não quer esses casos. Mas concordo que da forma que está a pergunta, ficou ambíguo.

Comment: Verdade, não tinha visto isso. Aí fica meio difícil.. hahahaha

Comment: @fernandosavio Atualizei a resposta com as 2 opções, valeu!

Comment: nao dá pra usar alguma forma de "non-consuming groups" para evitar essa coisa feia de ter que combinar as tres alternativas? penso em algo de um non-consuming-group para detectar o "z" na próxima palavra, em qualquer posição, combinado com o grupo de resposta da paalavra, aí da pra usar  `\w` que ja acha os acentos, e etc...

Comment: @jsbueno Tem razão, atualizei a resposta com essa alternativa, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Pode ser usado a função `filter` para ter o mesmo resultado:

```
lista = text.lower().split()  # transforma texto em lista de palavras com letras minusculas 
f_filtro = lambda x: 'z' in x  # Definine a função de filtro 
filtro = filter(f_filtro, texto.split())  # Filtra
lista_resultado = list(filtro)  # Cria resultado em lista
```

Ou podemos fazer a mesma coisa em uma linha:

```
lista_resultado = list(filter(lambda x: 'z' in x, text.lower().split()))
```

Comment: Um caso clássico em que código Python sem usar regex fica uma ordem de grandeza ou mais mais simples do que usando regex.

Comment: eu sugiro incorporar também uma versão com list-comprehension também, que fica ainda mais simples: 
`words = [word for word in text.split() if 'z' in word]`

Comment: Ficou ainda mais legível, jsbueno! Pensei em desempenho, mas usei o %timeit do jupyter console para ver tempo de processamento de cada solução e usando list-comprehension ainda teve um desempenho melhor. Muito bom.

Comment: map e filter são ferramentas anteriores às comprehensions do Python - além de ter a leitura simplificada (depois que alguém te explica como ler, claro), as comprehensiosions podem ser executadas com menos mudança de contexto (entrar e sair de funções) - o que as tornas mais eficientes.

Answer (score 0):

Pode fazer sentido usar expressões regulares para potencialmente controlar
a definição e limites de "palavra". `"Existem no zoo: zebra, ...".split() --> ["zoo:", "zebra,"]`

Eu escreveria:

```
import re

palavras = [x for x in re.findall(r'\w*[zZ]\w*', txt) if len(x)>1]
print(palavras)
```

(Ok: admito que esta escrita 'zZzZ' dá um pouco de sono)